# How to Switch to a Frame Visually, Without Running its Actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I've run to a problem. I've got a SWF that is divided into frames.
What I'm trying to do, is switch to one of my frames which has actionscript code, but I just want the visual elements to be displayed, without executing the actionscript code it contains.

I am trying to switch to this frame using `gotoAndStop("frame-name");`

I've tried to add a boolean value to the code in this frame, that decides whether or not it gets executed, I set the value the first time that frame's actionscript is executed, but this value is ignored as if using gotoAndStop
creates a new instance of that frame's actionscript code, so it doesn't retain the boolean value I set.

Is there any way to not allow actionscript execution of this frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, not really, at least not given how the solution 'seems' to work!

What you can do is to create another keyframe (f6 in editor I think) that looks identical and then do `gotoAndStop("other_frame")`.

As long as that keyframe doesn't have any code you're good to go :)

The most common solution for flash-development is to not have code inside your fla-file and instead have it in AS-files and only have visual elements inside the fla. That way you have full control of what is happening and when etc...